# Kafka TimestampConverter not found into confluentinc-connect-transforms-1.4.3

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I installed the MongoDB sink connector and the connect-transforms plugin because I would like to convert the value of a field from Unix epoch to Date before to write the data on Mongo but Kafka Connect throws the error

```
Invalid value class org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter for configuration transforms.ttl.t
ype: Transformation is abstract and cannot be created. Did you mean org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value, org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Key?
```

I had the doubt that there was no concrete class in the plugin, so I downloaded confluentinc/connect-transforms:1.4.3 zip and the TimestampConverter class is missing.

Anyone can help me, please? What I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**Did you mean `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value`, `org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Key`?**

You cannot have

```
transforms.ttl.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter
```

You need to [set the converter for either the record key or the record value](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/timestampconverter.html).

Also, this will not change a field **within a record**. If that is what you wanted, you should ideally change your producer code to do the correct conversion before the Connector consumes the topic, or just handle the conversion in your Mongo queries.

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation, but the error reported above is not my configuration which instead is `"transforms": "ttl", "transforms.ttl.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value", "transforms.ttl.format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "transforms.ttl.target.type": "Date", "transforms.ttl.field": "startDate"` So, yes I would like to change the type of a field in order to enable a TTL index on MongoDB.

Comment: As you suggested, I changed the producer so now the message contains this field `"ttl":{"$date":"2022-07-15 10:46:00.071"}` but the sink connector fails to write the data because the presence of "$date". How can I solve this issue? Using the TimestampConverter or something else? If with the TimestampConverter$Value the problem persists because I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Like I said, it won't work if the time is within a record. Notice the example given in the documentation... Or if it does work with records, then you have no `startDate` field there for it to transform. You'd have to use ExtractField to unwrap the `$date` field before conversion, but then you'd lose all other record information unless you also use HoistField transform after the conversion... I'm not familiar with Mongo or what a TTL index means to give a good example.

Answer (score -1):

The jars are present at the following co-ordinates. You could include them in the lib when running kafka connect

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/connect-transforms

The copy source is available at

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/transforms/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/TimestampConverter.java

Comment: This class should already be available from the Connect classpath since it included by default

Comment: @OneCricketeer you are right, the TimestampConverter class is available from the Connect classpath